# Create a sub-branch in Git

Tags: git

I want to create a sub-branch from an existing branch. My desired history would look like this:

```
--- master ---- 
               \-*--* model -*-*-
                                 \--*-- subbranch_model --*--
```

Does the `subbranch_model` will get the whole history from its parent branch `model`?
If it is, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: Just do `git branch subbranch_model model`. Did you try it? Yes, `subbranch_model` will get the whole history from `model`.

Comment: or, if you're already in `model` branch, `git checkout -b subbranch_model`

Comment: A "sub branch" is just a branch. There is no difference between branching from master or any other branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. You just base `subbranch_model` on `model` (make `model` starting-point of history for `subbranch_model`). It can be done simply like this: `git branch <branchname> [<start-point>]`. You can also do it during checkout into a new branch: `git checkout -b <branchname> [<start-point>]`.

```
git branch subbranch_model model
           ^-- branchname    ^
                             `-- start-point
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch for details.

The new branch (`subbranch_model`) will have all history up to `<start-point>` (`model`) but there's no "subbranch" it is just "a branch" that shares common history to certain point.

If you intend making changes to `model` and `subbranch_model` at same time, keep both these branches going you will also need to carry over any new changes made to `model` back to `subbranch_model` somehow (e.g. continuously `rebase` `subbranch_model` on top of updated `model`). See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase for more details on rebase.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, the sub-branch will get the history from model.

To subsequently keep the branch up to date with newer changes to model, you can do

```
git rebase model
```

To subsequently keep the branch up to date with master, you can do

```
git rebase master
```

When you refer to history, you may want to use the term 'changes' instead.  In some sense there is only one "history", however with branches there are many changes per branch.  Note that all branches contain all the 'history' at the point that they diverged (the branch was made).

Note that `git merge` is another way to bring in changes but `git rebase` is generally preferred because when you get conflicts it's generally easier to resolve them under the rebase model.